# Pinterest Not responding in android app

Tags: android

I have developed an application which has got sharing functionality using facebook,twitter and pinterest.There is an image and text to share.Each got a button on clicking the button will redirect the app to the sharing page.But the problem is on clicking the pinterest share button,it will check for the pinterest app if it is not present then it will redirect the user for the fresh installation of the pinterest app.But after the fresh installation of the app and when the user moves back to the app screen and clicking on the share button for pinterest is not getting any response.error that i am getting is

> 12-21 09:14:08.180: I/ApplicationPolicy(2273): isIntentDisabled start
>   :Intent {    act=com.pinterest.action.PIN_IT (has extras) }
>
> 12-21 09:14:08.180: I/ApplicationPolicy(2273): isIntentDisabled
>   resolve info :null
>
> 12-21 09:14:08.180: I`enter code here`/ApplicationPolicy(2273):
>   isIntentDisabled return :false

The code that i used for sharing to pinterest is

```
pinIt.setImageResource(R.drawable.share_pinterest);
        pinIt.setImageUrl(_imageUrl);
        pinIt.setUrl(_URL);
        pinIt.setDescription(getMessageToPost(_message));
        PinItButton.setPartnerId(PIN_IT_PARTNERID);
```

I have tested the scenario in Samsung S4,Note 2,HTC etc.But got the same issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you send some logs that the problem will be understandable.

Comment: The log that im getting is posted above..that is the only log im getting

Comment: oh ok than you tried the given code pinIt.setPartnerId(PIN_IT_PARTNERID); istead of PinItButton.setPartnerId(PIN_IT_PARTNERID);

Comment: hi hope you solved yours problem, if yes and if my answer is feasible please accept ans raise points

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look on

http://developers.pinterest.com/android/

It will solve yours problem as an example

i think what you are doing is   `PinItButton.setPartnerId(PIN_IT_PARTNERID);`

please have a try with this line if possible. i just looked and suggested you.

```
 pinIt.setPartnerId(PIN_IT_PARTNERID);
```

Comment: The issue is resolved.The problem was with the 2.1.3 sdk version of pinterest.They have uploaded new 2.1.4v of their sdk.Thank u for the help.

Comment: oh ok than thats great :)